# Writing Binary file at certain address

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is read a blank file with no extension. From there, open the file and read it at a certain offset. Here's what I've done for that:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open 234cec File";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));

            string Texture1 = null;

            for (int i = 0x2D670DE; i <= 0x2D6712F; i++)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Position = i;
                Texture1 += br.ReadChar().ToString();
            }
            br.Close();

            textBox1.Text = Texture1;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

The program works just fine and displays text in a textbox from what it read.

However, I want to be able to write back in the file, from what's in the textbox it read, with a Save button. 
i.e. from what I modify in the textbox, then have it save back to my file (at the specified address) WITHOUT changing the file size (like replacing what's there).
The file I'm reading is a kinda big file like 120MB and it doesn't just contain text, it also contains other hex/code and such.

My problem is, I'm clueless as to what line I should do for my Save button after I modify what it read in the Textbox. Any help?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `File.Open()` and you'll see how to open a file for writing without truncating it.

Comment: Ill take a look. Would you mean Google File.Open()?

Comment: Start by creating a `FileStream`.  You can set its `Position` property or call its `Seek` method to position the file pointer.  You can then create other objects on top of that, e.g. a `StreamReader` to read text and a `StreamWriter` to write text.  Just be aware that you can't really insert or remove bytes that way.  Whatever you write must be the same length in bytes as what you're replacing.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this?